How to share logging scope with an injected service
I'm writing a .NET 8 web application, C#, and I'm trying to share the logging scope that I establish at the start of a method. I've boiled everything down so you have a REST controller like this:
public class LoggingTestController : ControllerBase
{
    public LoggingTestController(ILogger<LoggingTestController> log, SomeService someService)
    {
        this.Log = log;
        this.SomeService = someService;
    }

    private ILogger Log { get; }
    private SomeService SomeService { get; }
    
    [HttpGet("/log-test")]
    public IActionResult LogTest()
    {
        using (this.Log.BeginScope("SomeScope"))
        {
            this.Log.LogInformation("This is logged in the controller");
            this.SomeService.LogSomething();
            return Content("Hey.");
        }
    }
}

And then a service like:
public class SomeService
{
    public SomeService(ILogger<SomeService> log)
    {
        this.Log = log;
    }
    
    private ILogger<SomeService> Log { get; }

    public void LogSomething()
    {
        Log.LogInformation("This message is logged from the service");
    }
}

I'm injecting the service in the startup like with a simple builder.Services.AddScoped<SomeService>();
From what I understand, as the service is Scoped it should share the same logging scope as the controller in which it's being added. However, this scope is not turning up in the log messages from the service, but does in the log messages from the controller (I've got my own logging provide that shows the scope if available).
Am I missing something? Is it possible to share the logging scope from a controller method to an injected service?

I think the problems is not related to the "SomeService" service. It is related to the registered instance of ILogger. How are you registering in the DependencyInjection the ILogger? You have 2 different ones as a first glance, ILogger in the controller and ILogger in the SomeService service, so I bet the injector injects different instances in each place.

you could try to troubleshoot the issue by setting "Console": {           "IncludeScopes": true         }  in appsetting file.  and  as you are using custom logging provider, double-check its implementation if it properly handles scope information. A custom provider can sometimes ignore or mishandle the scope context.

Can you please share a full [mre] which could easily be run?

with the code you have shared here is the result image. it would be great you could share reproducible sample with us

Thanks for the comments. I will go back and see what happens if I use the built in console logging provider rather than my own.

May I know whether it worked or not when we use the built in console logging provider?
